# I want to write junit for my kafka consumer but not sure how can I provide mock data when calling .subscription

Tags: java, apache-kafka, junit, reactive-kafka

```
protected void startConsumer() { 

props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, applicationIdConfig); props.put(SCHEMAREG_URL, schemaregUrl); props.put(SSL_KEYSTORE_ALIAS, sslKeystoreAlias); props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServerConfig); props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, securityProtocolConfig); props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, new File(TRUSTSTORE_FILE_NAME).getAbsolutePath()); props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, sslTrustStorePasswordConfig); props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, new File(KEYSTORE_FILE_NAME).getAbsolutePath()); props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, sslKeyStorePasswordConfig); props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEY_PASSWORD_CONFIG, sslKeyPasswordConfig); props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServerConfig); props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupIdConfig); props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, autoOffsetResetConfig); props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class); props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAxonDeSerializer.class); 

//How to set mock data from junit for below code 

ReceiverOptions options = ReceiverOptions.create(props).subscription(Collections.singleton(topicIdConfig)) .addAssignListener(partitions -> log.debug("onPartitionsAssigned {}", partitions)) .addRevokeListener(partitions -> log.debug("onPartitionsRevoked {}", partitions)); 

// Set up to receive messages
 KafkaReceiver receiver = KafkaReceiver.create(options); 
receiver.doOnConsumer(c -> { c.assignment().forEach(a -> log.info("Subscribed to " + a.topic() + ":" + a.partition())); return c; }); 
Flux> recordFlux = receiver.receive(); fluxWorkflow(recordFlux); }
```

Comment: You should use `TopologyTestDriver` to test a Streams application

Comment: @OneCricketeer Is topology test drive support reactive Kafka? Is there any example or link

Comment: It's built into Kafka. Doesn't require external frameworks https://www.confluent.io/blog/test-kafka-streams-with-topologytestdriver/